# Lavaan - Model with formative indicators not identified

Tags: lavaan

I know that this was already treated. However, I still have problems and get the following warning:

In lav_model_vcov(lavmodel = lavmodel, lavsamplestats = lavsamplestats,  :
lavaan WARNING:
Could not compute standard errors! The information matrix could
not be inverted. This may be a symptom that the model is not
identified.

I specified the model like this:

```
library(lavaan)

masterModel <- ' 
             # latent variable definitions               
              #reflective
              hedonism =~ Hedonism.1 + Hedonism.2 + Hedonism.3 
              novelty =~ Novelty.1 + Novelty.2 + Novelty.3
              cultural =~ Local.culture.1 + Local.culture.2
              refreshment =~  Refreshment.1 + Refreshment.2 + Refreshment.3
              involvement =~ Involvement.1 + Involvement.2 + Involvement.3
              knowledge =~ Knowledge.1 + Knowledge.2
              meaningfulness =~ Meaningfulness.1 + Meaningfulness.2
              engagement =~ Engagement.1 + Engagement.2 + Engagement.3
              intention =~ Intention.to.use.1 + Intention.to.use.2 +Intention.to.use.3 
              
             # formative
              usability <~ 1*Application.design + Application.utility + User.interface.graphic + User.interface.input + User.interface.output + Overall.perceived.quality
              experience <~ 1*hedonism + novelty + cultural + refreshment + involvement + knowledge + meaningfulness  
              
             # regressions
             experience ~ usability
             engagement ~ experience
             intention ~ engagement '
             
fit1<- sem(masterModel, data=master_thesis)  
summary(fit1,standardized=TRUE, fit.measures=TRUE)
```

If you need my data, you can access the data here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lzsyx87jx0l5qle/AR-R.csv?dl

Thank you for your help,
Margit

Answer (score 0):

According to Kline (2016) Principles and Practice of Structural Equation Modeling, 4th Edition, MacCallum and Browne (1993 The use of causal indicators in covariance structures models: Some practical issues. Psychological Bulletin, 114, 533-41) 'noted that in order for the disturbance variance of a factor with causal indicators only to be identified, that factor must have direct effects on at least two other endogenous variables, such as factors with effect indicators'. Your model does not meet this requirement.